# Prove that every holomorphic function $f:\overline{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

**Exercise:**

> Prove that every holomorphic function $f:\overline{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is polynomial.

**my solution:**

from the Cauchy estimate we get $$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\oint_{γ}^{}\frac{f(ζ)}{(ζ-z_0)^{n+1}}dζ$$

$$\Rightarrow |f^{(n)}(z_0)|\leq \oint_{0}^{2\pi}\left |\frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{(re^{it})^{n+1}}ie^{it}dt   \right |
\leq \left | \frac{f(z_0+re^{it})}{r^n} \right |$$

I let $r\rightarrow \infty$ and I get that $f^{(n)}$ is zero, therefore $f$ is a polynomial.

**Questions:**

1. Does that mean that $f\equiv 0$? Since $f$ is holomorphic and $f^{(n)}=0$ from the taylor expantion we get

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } f^{(n)}(z_0)\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{n!}=0 $$

2.Is my solution correct, are there any other solutions to this problem ?

Comment: Is $\overline{\mathbb C}$ the Riemann sphere?

Comment: Your solution can not be correct because $f$ can be any constant.

Comment: Note that you can much simpler argue with Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop yes its the set $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$

Comment: if it is constant then its trivial a polynomial, nothing to prove there.

Comment: The more interesting question is to find holomorphoc functions to $\overline{\mathbb C}$

Comment: I think the Question would be more interesting if the codomain were also the Riemann sphere.  As stated the function $f$ can only be polynomial if it is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution contains a couple of flaws.
First off, you did not actually use that $f$ is defined at $\infty$, so it cannot be correct.
Secondly, your Cauchy integral formula is missing a factor $\frac{n!}{2\pi i}$.
Thirdly, you cannot simply drop the integral and still have $t$ in the argument of $f$.
EDIT: the main reason your argument does not work in the end is that you cannot justify that the limit as $r \rightarrow \infty$ actually is $0$ without invoking that $f$ is bounded.

The answer as to how to show this is given in Martin R's comment.
Liouville's theorem tells you that any bounded entire function is constant.
Your function is entire and the Riemann sphere is compact, hence the image of $f$ is compact, hence $f$ is bounded.
Note that $f$ cannot be a non-constant polynomial because any such polynomial $p$ satisfies $p(\infty) = \infty$.